# Passing an initializer list to a vector based constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

I currently have the following code

```
class test
{
   public:
   test(std::vector<std::string> str)
   {
   }
   test()
   {
   }
    const std::multimap<int,  std::multimap<int, test>> _var= {
                 {0x01,  {
                            {
                                0x0f, {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
                            }
                         }
                 }
        };   
};

int main()
{  
  test t;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:29:9: error: could not convert '{{1, {{15, {"A", "B", "C", "D"}}}}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const std::multimap<int, std::multimap<int, test> >'
         };
         ^
```

I wanted to know why passing {"A", "B", "C", "D"} to `std::vector<std::string> str)` is failing ? Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: what's an error?

Comment: ok let me update

Comment: You have more than 1 user-defined conversion happening. Fix it by doing `vector<string>{"A,","B","C"}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another pair of braces. Use:

```
0x0f, {{"A", "B", "C", "D"}}
```

Without that, the compiler tries to construct a `test` using the arguments `"A", "B", "C", "D"`, as if `test{"A", "B", "C", "D"}`, which does not work.

Comment: @Rajeshwar, that code looks good to me. It works fine on my computer.

Comment: This technically causes a crash. I just posted a new question based on this

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
class test
{
   public:
   test(std::vector<std::string> str)
   {
   }
   test()
   {
   }
    const std::multimap<int,  std::multimap<int, test>> _var= {
                 {0x01,  {
                            {
                                0x0f, std::vector<std::string>{"A", "B", "C", "D"}
                            }
                         }
                 }
        };   
};
```

Nevertheless, you should never pass containers by value.

An alternative approach is to use an std::initializer_list in your ctor, then your code can be written as:

```
class test
{
   public:
   test(std::initializer_list<std::string> str)
   {
   }
   test()
   {
   }
    const std::multimap<int,  std::multimap<int, test>> _var= {
                 {0x01,  {
                            {
                                0x0f, {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
                            }
                         }
                 }
        };   
};
```